# How to use a where clause with a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Student`

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name |
| 2 | Name |

Table `Classes`

| Id | Name | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | class1 | 2 |
| 2 | class1 | 3 |

and a join table

| StudentId | ClassId | Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 |

and the query

```
select sum(scr.Income) 
from Student s 
left join StudentClassRelation scr on scr.classId = s.Id 
left join Class c on c.Id = scr.classId and c.Number > 4
```

I want to move `c.Number > 4` on the second line in order to receive only the income from classes with number greater than 4. I cannot change the query significantly because it is a part of a bigger one. I need to filter `StudentClassRelation` somehow

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
);

CREATE TABLE Class
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Number int
);

CREATE TABLE StudentClassRelation
(
    Income int,
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    ClassID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ClassID) REFERENCES Class(Id),
    UNIQUE (StudentID, ClassID)
);

INSERT INTO Class (Id, Name, Number) 
VALUES (1, '1', 1), (2, '5', 5)

INSERT INTO Student (Id, Name) 
VALUES (1, '1'), (2, '5')

INSERT INTO StudentClassRelation (StudentID, ClassID, Income) 
VALUES (1, 1, 10), (2, 1, 20), (2, 2, 5)
```

Comment: Why the `LEFT JOIN`s here? You are `SUM`ing the value of `scr.Income`, and not grouping, so that means that you only want the rows where there is a match in the table `StudentClassRelation`. As for  the `LEFT JOIN` to `class`, do your `StudentClassRelation ` have a one to many relationship with `Class`?

Comment: Using an `INNER JOIN` would probably be the simplest fix - [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4df19bb19f2fad6b023314b3e339e6ec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the join to `StudentClassRelation` as a `LEFT JOIN` and apply a filter based on a column in the class table, you could use `LEFT JOIN` to a subquery that uses an `INNER JOIN` on Class, e.g.

```
SELECT  SUM(scr.Income)
FROM    Student AS s
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  scr.StudentId, scr.Income
            FROM    StudentClassRelation AS scr
                    INNER JOIN Class AS c
                        ON c.Id = scr.ClassId
            WHERE   c.Number > 4
        ) AS scr
            ON scr.StudentId = s.Id;
```

You can however rewrite this in a less verbose way as follows:

```
SELECT  SUM(scr.Income)
FROM    Student AS s
        LEFT JOIN (StudentClassRelation AS scr
            INNER JOIN Class AS c
                ON c.Id = scr.ClassId
                AND c.Number > 4)
            ON scr.StudentId = s.Id;
```

The execution plans of the two are exactly the same, which is "better" would be entirely personal preference as to which you find more readable. You spend more time reading code than writing it, so the least verbose method does not equate to the best method.

Also worth noting, that if this was the entire query, there is no difference at all from simply using `INNER JOIN` throughout

```
SELECT  SUM(scr.Income)
FROM    Student AS s
        INNER JOIN StudentClassRelation AS scr
            ON scr.classId = s.Id
        INNER JOIN Class AS c
            ON c.Id = scr.classId
            AND c.Number > 4;
```

But since you have mentioned that this is part of a larger query, I will assume that there is more to it than just the posted sample, and there is in fact a need for the `LEFT JOIN` to `StudentClassRelation`, e.g. If you were to do something like:

```
SELECT  s.Id, Income = SUM(scr.Income)
FROM    Student AS s
        LEFT JOIN (StudentClassRelation AS scr
            INNER JOIN Class AS c
                ON c.Id = scr.ClassId
                AND c.Number > 4)
            ON scr.StudentId = s.Id
GROUP BY s.Id;
```

This would yield different results to the version with an `INNER JOIN` to both tables

```
SELECT  s.Id, Income = SUM(scr.Income)
FROM    Student AS s
        INNER JOIN StudentClassRelation AS scr
            ON scr.classId = s.Id
        INNER JOIN Class AS c
            ON c.Id = scr.classId
            AND c.Number > 4
GROUP BY s.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a workaround (2options) if u dont want to change the rest of your query

```
select sum(scr.Income) from Student s 
left join StudentClassRelation scr on scr.classId = s.Id    
    and EXISTS(select top 1 1 from Class where Class.Id = scr.classId and Class.Number > 4)
```

--> 5

```
select sum(scr.Income) from Student s 
left join StudentClassRelation scr on scr.classId = s.Id    
    and (select top 1 Class.Number from Class where Class.Id = scr.classId) > 4
```

--> 5

Is it working as expected?

EDIT: my bad, the solution provided by @GarethD is way better (using inner join instead of left join)